# Can't understand how storing addresses in void * and jumping to them using goto works

Tags: c, goto

I'm reading the GNU C manual and reached this section about the goto statement:

> As an extension, GCC allows a goto statement to jump to an address
> specified by a void* variable. To make this work, you also need to
> take the address of a label by using the unary operator && (not &).
> Here is a contrived example:
>
> ```
> enum Play { ROCK=0, PAPER=1, SCISSORS=2 };
> enum Result { WIN, LOSE, DRAW };
>
> static enum Result turn (void) 
> {
>   const void * const jumptable[] = {&&rock, &&paper, &&scissors};
>   enum Play opp;                /* opponent’s play */
>   goto *jumptable[select_option (&opp)];
>  rock:
>   return opp == ROCK ? DRAW : (opp == PAPER ? LOSE : WIN);
>  paper:
>   return opp == ROCK ? WIN  : (opp == PAPER ? DRAW : LOSE);
>  scissors:
>   return opp == ROCK ? LOSE : (opp == PAPER ? WIN  : DRAW);
> }
> ```

What is the second `const` in `const void * const jumptable[]` for? The declaration is basically `array of const pointers to const void`, right? But I can't understand what that means, sorry if it sounds stupid.

Then, what does &opp mean? What does the code do with its address? What is select_option()?

Comment: The `const`s are irrelevant for the actual feature; `void* jumptable[]` would work just as well.

Comment: Following [the clockwise/spiral rule](https://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html), the declaration `const void * const jumptable[]` declares `jumpotable` as an array of constant pointers to `void`, and the data that each pointer is pointing to is constant. That means the elements in the array are constant, and the data they are pointing to are also constant.

Comment: [`const void * const jumptable[]`: declare jumptable as array of const pointer to const void](https://cdecl.org/?q=const+void+*+const+jumptable%5B%5D)

Comment: *"The declaration is basically array of const pointers to const void"* That sounds correct. Can you elaborate what you don't understand about it?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat what I don't understand is what a const void is. I thought a void * variable was basically a pointer you could use to store any type of pointer but what is const void *? What does the const keyword do there?

Comment: This is also a pointer to any type, but it doesn't let you modify what it points to (akin to `const int *`) (at least not without casting the pointer to a different pointer type without the const). E.g. `const void *a = 0; const int *b = a;` compiles, but `int *c = a;` doesn't.

Comment: @hansoko "what I don't understand is what a const void is" That's perfectly reasonable, nobody understands that. The left const here doesn't make a whole lot of sense, but the people who write all these useless gcc extensions aren't known to make sense. This feature here is very much not recommended to be used for any purpose.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between const int\*, const int \* const, and int const \*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-and-int-const)

Answer (score 1):

When `const` is placed on the right side of a pointer `*` declaration, it makes the pointer itself read-only. If placed left of the `*`, the pointed-at data is read-only (which doesn't make sense in case of function pointers since functions cannot be read-only, but maybe it does in case of this non-standard GNU spaghetti feature).

When designing conventional jump tables with function pointers rather than labels, it is convention to make the table itself read-only. For 2 reasons:

- Changing where to jump dynamically in run-time is likely undesirable. Normally you don't want or need that amount of extreme flexibility. So the jump table should be designed at compile-time and stay that way. Intentional or accidental writes to it should be blocked.
- In embedded systems, the `*  const` read-only qualifier means that the jump table will get allocated in non-volatile flash rather than RAM. Which means that it becomes allocated in true read-only memory, but also that you save valuable RAM - in the general microcontroller programming scenario, RAM is more valuable than flash.

---

> Then, what does &opp mean?

I can't tell for sure since you didn't include the `select_option` function, but likely it's a function of this nature:

```c
enum Play select_option (enum Play* p)
{
  *p = some_decision();
  return *p;
}
```

That is, the function changes the passed variable but also returns it for supposed function call convenience. Instead of declaring it with return type `void`, in which case we'd have to write

```
select_option (&opp);
goto *jumptable[opp];
```

Which admittedly is not a problem, since that code is much more readable and the "most sub expressions on a single line wins a price" form of programming is very bad practice.

In general, it is actually considered questionable API design to have a function return the same value through multiple ways, both as return and as one of the parameters. But that's another story.